# MySQL creating doesn't work Error 1064

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have this query:

```
CREATE TABLE
    `rooms` (
    `roomname` VARCHAR NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = MyISAM";
```

But it doesn't work I get this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL ) ENGINE = MyISAM"' at line 3
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: You didn't specify a length for varchar

Comment: Additionally PRIMARY KEY's are always NOT NULL, therefore NOT NULL is not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE
    `rooms` (
    `roomname` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    `price` DOUBLE NOT NULL
)
ENGINE = MyISAM";
```

you need to specify the length

Comment: NOT NULL is not required on PRIMARY KEY

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to specify VARCHAR(length). The length determines how many character you can use as your room name.